# How to implement seaborn graphs into tkinter without them losing their interactivity?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, seaborn, tk-toolkit

My code to put the graph onto a canvas

```
sns.set()
df = pd.DataFrame(stocks, columns=['Date', 'Close'])
f = plt.Figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = f.subplots()
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date', y='Close', ax=ax)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1)
```

The graph shows x and y values when you move the mouse

[image: The graph shows x and y values when you move the mouse]

When putting it on a canvas it loses the ability to show x and y values

[image: meh]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, and it was to add NavigationToolbar2Tk from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg

```
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, chart_frame)
toolbar.update()
```